# Why compiler selects wrong overload in this case?

Tags: c++

Consider this rather simple code ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/P34dcvnsb)):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string f(char const* fmt, ...);
size_t f(char* buf, size_t sz, char const* fmt, ...);

void bar()
{
    f("%c%s", 'A', "AAA");
}
```

Type of first parameter is supposed to be `char const[5]`, which means second overload should not be even considered. And yet compiler (even though it complains a bit) selects it (as you could see in generated assembly).

Can someone explain exactly what happens here?

**Notes:**

- MSVC fails to compile this
- my GCC version 8.3.1-3 fails to compile it too

Comment: My MSVC (VS 2019) compiles it just fine and selects the first version.

Comment: For MSVC, `/permissive-` is your friend. Sadly, strict conformance is enabled only upon opt-in.

Comment: @AdrianMole - VS changed its default project template in recent years. `/permissive-` is set by default. In the command line, it isn't however.

Comment: clang compiles; gcc error; mcvc compiles - live - https://godbolt.org/z/6M1axYza5

Comment: @RichardCritten So, gcc bug?

Comment: GCC bug (this one, I believe https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95596).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Compiler differences usually need the [language-lawyer] tag to resolve - I am not that level.

Comment: You can get a temporary work around by `f(+"%c%s", 'A', "AAA");`

Comment: @RichardCritten Perfect!

Comment: Also worth noting gcc selects the correct overload with the `-pedantic` flag